# Content, half ring, outer measure

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $\mu\colon\mathfrak{h}\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be a content on the half ring $\mathfrak{h}$ above $X$ and consider the corresponding outer measure $\eta(A):=\inf\left\{\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\mu(A_n): A_n\in\mathfrak{}, n\in\mathbb{N},A\subset\bigcup\limits_{n\geq 1}A_n\right\}$.
> >     Show: If $\mu$ is no pre-measure, there exists a $A\in\mathfrak{h}$ with $\eta(A)<\mu(A)$.

Could you please help me to show that? I am rather uninspired.

I give you a prove that I found but do not understand.

If $\mu$ is no pre-measure, so there is a sequence $(A_n)$ of disjoint sets in $\mathfrak{h}$ with $A:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\in\mathfrak{h}$ and $\mu(A)\neq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)$. Using the continuation $\nu$ of $\mu$ it is $\mu(A)\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)$ so it is $\mu(A)>\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)\geq\eta(A)$.

I do not understand why A is in the halfring and which continuation is meant.

Comment: I'm trying to find the definition of half ring but I can't. Can you just explain it or shoot a link that does?

Comment: Of course. A set $\mathfrak{h}\subset\mathcal{P}(X)$ is a half ring above $X$, if $\mathfrak{h}$ fullfills the following points: 1) $\emptyset\in\mathfrak{h}$, 2) $A,B\in\mathfrak{h}\Rightarrow A\cap B\in\mathfrak{h}$, 3) For all $A,B\in\mathfrak{h}$ there are disjoint $C_1,...,C_n\in\mathfrak{h}$, so that $A\setminus B=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}C_k$.

Comment: For the record, the close vote is totally unappropriate. 

Is your half ring closed under finite unions too? Because the definition of content requires that $\mu$ is finitely additive, i.e. $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$ when $A \cap B = \varnothing$.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot say if it is closed under finite unions.

Comment: I voted to close. "Could you please help me to show that? I am rather uninspired." is most certainly a case of "This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level."

Comment: @math12 : But then how can you say it is a content? I mean, $\mu(A \cup B)$ does not make sense if $A \cup B \notin \mathfrak h$.

Comment: @mrf : Yes, but it's not because a question is not detailed enough for us to understand the question immediately that we should dismiss it. I am currently discussing with OP to clarify his thoughts, and in that sense I think I am being helpful and that the question is appropriate. In terms of incompleteness, we all know we've seen worse.

Comment: @math12 : If you want to seek an answer to your question (either from yourself or us), clarify your hypotheses ; what is a half ring? What is a content? Are the definitions coherent? What does it mean to be no pre-measure? Then get the implications and we can have something to work with. Feel free to edit your question to both 1) show some work 2) clarify your question.

Comment: I have edited my question by adding a proof that I found.

Answer (score 0):

That was actually my first guess, but I don't totally understand the hypotheses so I didn't know if my moves were legitimate. Let me try to explain what I "see" in that proof.

We always have $\mu \left( \bigcup_{n \ge 1} A_n \right) \ge \sum_{n \ge 1} A_n$, because 
$$
\mu \left( \bigcup_{n \ge 1} A_n \right) = \mu \left( \left[ \bigcup_{n > N} A_n \right] \cup A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \dots \cup A_n \right) = \mu \left( \bigcup_{n > N} A_n \right) + \sum_{n =1}^N \mu(A_n) \ge \sum_{n=1}^N \mu(A_n).
$$
(In the first step I used finite additivity of the content $\mu$, and the second step the positivity of $\mu$.) Since the lower bound is true for all $N$, it is true for the limit when $N \to \infty$ : 
$$
\mu \left( \bigcup_{n \ge 1} A_n \right) \ge \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n =1}^N \mu(A_n) = \sum_{n \ge 1} \mu(A_n).
$$
Since $A = \bigcup_{n \ge 1} A_n$, we see that $\eta(A) \le \sum_{n \ge 1} \mu(A_n) \le \mu(A)$. Because $\mu$ is no pre-measure, we can choose the sequence $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ such that $\mu(A) > \sum_{n \ge 1} \mu(A_n)$ and that finishes the proof.

I think that all you need to assume in this statement is that $\mathfrak h$ is closed under countable unions, but that would make it a $\sigma$-algebra, or something very close to that. I haven't given it enough thought, but you should.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thank you. And you are right, my problem is to see why $A\in\mathfrak{h}$. Maybe it is meant $\sigma(\mathfrak{h})$ and it is a mistake?

Comment: Maybe the trick is to consider the continuation of $\mu$ on the ring that is produced by $\mathfrak{h}$? Because a Ring is closed under finite unions.

Comment: I think the main point is that half rings are closed under countable unions of DISJOINT sets within the halfring.

Comment: @math12 : Like I said, get your definitions straight, then we can talk. Otherwise we're speaking in the air and I have no context so I cannot guess what are the right definitions. I'm sorry I can't do more than that.